# can someone help me make a discord count game

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is my code but it does not work i also removed the channel id
so what i want is the user send the message 1 then 2 and if someone does 4 it will send you messed up but i dont know how to make it so i knows if a user messed up

```
let count = 0
client.on('message', ({channel, content, member}) => {
  if (channel.id === '') {
    if (member.user.bot) return
    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
      count++

    } else if (count === count+++) {
    
      channel.send(`${member} messed up at ${count} im gonna reset the count to 0`).catch(console.error)
      count = 0
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service

Comment: ah yes sorry ill update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of more information, your problem is probably: `} else if (count === count+++) {`, if the number wasn't correct, it would check this, but `count === count+++` is not always gonna be true, that's why the message isn't being send

```js
let count = 0;

// If you look at the docs (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate)
// you would see that `message` is deprecated and that you should use `messageCreate` instead.

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if (message.channel.id !== '') return;
  if (message.member.user.bot) return;

  if (Number(parseInt(message.content)) === count + 1) count++;
  else {
    channel.send(`${message.member} messed up at ${count}, I'm gonna reset the count to 0`).catch(console.error)
    count = 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: This could be further simplified to `if (Number(message.content) != ++count) { /* send messed up count message, set count to 0 */ }`. Eliminates the need for an `else` altogether.

Comment: yes thank you a lot it works and i also modified it message create does not work i instead used a normal message event